# Node.js Request Module....sending json in body for api request with put

Tags: node.js, request

I am using Node.js and the request module. I am trying to make a post request api(restfull) but it's not sending the request correctly. I can make this work in curl and in python's request module, but not the node.js request module:

```
var request = require('request');

token = 'sfgsfsf';

var options = {
    url: 'https://_rest_full_api
    headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': token
    },
    body: {
        'status' : 'pending'
    },
    json: true,
    method: 'put'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
        console.log(info);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.body);
    }
}

request(options, callback); 


SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request.callback [as _callback] (/home/one/try.js:19:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/one/node_modules/request/request.js:122:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/one/node_modules/request/request.js:888:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/one/node_modules/request/request.js:839:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the json option set to true, request is automatically parsing the body for you to an object. You are re-parsing the body with this line:

```
var info = JSON.parse(body)
```

When you try to parse an object, you get that message:

```
$ node
> var t = {};
> JSON.parse(t);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Comment: Thanks. How come it didn't say 'Unexpected token b' for(body) instead of Unexpected token o?

Comment: Because body is a variable containing an object. It's trying to parse body.toString(), which is '[object Object]'.

Comment: try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idempotent-json, it won't reparse objects if they are already parsed

Answer (score 2):

```
var request = require('request');
 function updateClient(postData){
            var clientServerOptions = {
                uri: 'http://'+clientHost+''+clientContext,
                body: JSON.stringify(postData),
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            request(clientServerOptions, function (error, response) {
                console.log(error,response.body);
                return;
            });
        }
```

at the client side.And,

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var port = 9000;

app.put('/sample/put/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log('receiving data ...');
    console.log('body is ',req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

at the server side.